# Pure death processes

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes

If  $P_n (t)=\Pr (N (t)=n)$ and $N (0)=a$, how can I show that in a pure death process $$P_{(a-1)}(t)=a (e^{\mu t }-1)e^{-a \mu t}.$$

I showed that $P_a(t)=e^{-a \mu t}$.

In fact I want to show

$$P_k(t)= {a \choose k} (e^{\mu t }-1)^{a-k}e^{-a \mu t}$$ where $\mu $ is the death rate.

Comment: Hint: The RHS is $a(1-e^{-\mu t})e^{-(a-1)\mu t}=a(1-p)p^{a-1}$ for $p=e^{-\mu t}$ and $p$ is the probability of a quite natural event in this context.